# How to generate dynamic drop down on page load using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i have five html screens and will be  navigating to the page based on the role selected on the dropdown in the page?

Here is the code i am using for generating the drop downs.

```js
var roleByCatgory = {
            Education: ["Schools", "Colleges"],
            Operations: ["Director", "Controller"],
            Entertainment: ["Music", "dance"]

        }

        function cat(value) {
            if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
            else {
                var catOptions = "";
                catOptions += "<option disabled selected>--Select--</option>";
                for (categoryId in roleByCatgory[value]) {
                    catOptions += "<option>" + roleByCatgory[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
                }
                $("#category").html(catOptions);
                var dropdown_role = document.getElementById("category").value;

                $("#category").on('change', function () {

                    if ($("#category").val() == "Schools") {
                        location.href = "school.html";
                    }
                    else if ($("#category").val() == "Colleges") {
                        location.href = "Colleges.html";
                    }
                    else if ($("#category").val() == "Director") {
                        location.href = "Director.html";
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4  col-lg-offset-2 col-xs-6">
        <!-- modification to be done for dropdown -->
        <select name="Maindropdown" class="form-control dropdown " id="Maindropdown" onchange="cat(this.value);">
            <option value="--" selected>--Select--</option>
            <option value="Education" selected>Education</option>
            <option value="Operations">Operations</option>
            <option value="Entertainment">Entertainment</option>

        </select>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input">
                <select name="category" class="form-control dropdown " style="border-radius: 1em;" id="category"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

on page load i am not able to get the second drop down values? on page navigation i should able to display the current values of both drop down values .

Comment: Please insert your code to code snippet.

Comment: When and where you calling you function cat(vale) ?

Comment: @ArjunChoudhary `<select name="Maindropdown" class="form-control dropdown" id="Maindropdown" onchange="cat(this.value);">`.

Answer (score 0):

@BhavaniSankar is you want to keep both drop down visible on screen, you need to use iframe for it.

Check this:

```js
 var roleByCatgory = {
            Education: ["Schools", "Colleges"],
            Operations: ["Director", "Controller"],
            Entertainment: ["Music", "dance"]

        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            cat($("#Maindropdown").val());
        });


        function cat(value) {
            if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
            else {
                var catOptions = "";
                catOptions += "<option disabled selected>--Select--</option>";
                for (categoryId in roleByCatgory[value]) {
                    catOptions += "<option>" + roleByCatgory[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
                }
                $("#category").html(catOptions);
                var dropdown_role = document.getElementById("category").value;

                $("#category").on('change', function () {

                    if ($("#category").val() == "Schools") {
                        $('#iFrame1').attr("src","school.html");
                    }
                    else if ($("#category").val() == "Colleges") {
                        $('#iFrame1').attr("src","Colleges.html");
                    }
                    else if ($("#category").val() == "Director") {
                        $('#iFrame1').attr("src", "Director.html");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4  col-lg-offset-2 col-xs-6">
        <!-- modification to be done for dropdown -->
        <select name="Maindropdown" class="form-control dropdown " id="Maindropdown" onchange="cat(this.value);">
            <option value="--" selected>--Select--</option>
            <option value="Education" selected>Education</option>
            <option value="Operations">Operations</option>
            <option value="Entertainment">Entertainment</option>

        </select>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input">
                <select name="category" class="form-control dropdown " style="border-radius: 1em;" id="category"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <iframe id="iFrame1" height="100%" width="100%" style="min-height:300px;border:none"></iframe>
```

There is one more solution is available, that you load html content using jquery ajax request.

Comment: Thank you @saAction . i want to load the second drop down on the page load but here it is showing as a empty on change only i could see second drop down , how that can be done?

Comment: @BhavaniSankar, i have edited the code, applied jQuery ready function to check selected value on page load.

Comment: Thank you @saAction. it is really help full for me thank you.

Comment: The page is not being directed to another html. i could see the content in the same page. is it possible to do without iframe

Comment: Yes, It can be done by jQuery $("#div1").load("school.html");

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jQuery ajax method using "load()" function

Check this:

```js
 var roleByCatgory = {
            Education: ["Schools", "Colleges"],
            Operations: ["Director", "Controller"],
            Entertainment: ["Music", "dance"]

        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            cat($("#Maindropdown").val());
        });


        function cat(value) {
            if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
            else {
                var catOptions = "";
                catOptions += "<option disabled selected>--Select--</option>";
                for (categoryId in roleByCatgory[value]) {
                    catOptions += "<option>" + roleByCatgory[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
                }
                $("#category").html(catOptions);
                var dropdown_role = document.getElementById("category").value;

                $("#category").on('change', function () {

                    if ($("#category").val() == "Schools") {
                        $("#div1").load("school.html");
                    }
                    else if ($("#category").val() == "Colleges") {
                        $("#div1").load("Colleges.html");
                    }
                    else if ($("#category").val() == "Director") {
                        $("#div1").load("Director.html");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4  col-lg-offset-2 col-xs-6">
        <!-- modification to be done for dropdown -->
        <select name="Maindropdown" class="form-control dropdown " id="Maindropdown" onchange="cat(this.value);">
            <option value="--" selected>--Select--</option>
            <option value="Education">Education</option>
            <option value="Operations">Operations</option>
            <option value="Entertainment">Entertainment</option>

        </select>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input">
                <select name="category" class="form-control dropdown " style="border-radius: 1em;" id="category"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="div1" style="min-height:200px;width:100%;border:solid 1px #c6c6c6"></div>
```

Now the content is loading inside div tag when you select the drop down list.

Comment: Thank you so much @saAction. u just made my day...
but i have some  other things to be done. i just need ur help in this.
1.on the page load for the first page of application should nt show --select --- should show the role.

2.how to make the selected value to be there on the page
i have tried this but it is showing the --select---
$(("#category").val()).attr("selected","selected");

Comment: hi. @saAcion.. Now i am able to navigate without any errors, my only concern is how can i display the selected values in the category when it is navigated to other page ?

Comment: We are using jQuery ajax to get content from another page, it is not loading entire page, Two drop down list in header for Category and Sub-Category will stay selected, we are not loading entire page but displaying other page's content inside `'#div1'` tag of the main page.